# std::vector dimension, "tetris" shapes allowed?

Tags: c++

Hi I have a question about the use of vectors in  in c++, I am working on a problem of simulating particle movement through containers by random motion. I have a need for adding and removing particles as they meet or fail to meet certain criterion and for this purpose I found the vector class very handy, however I am new to c++ and a have a problem of efficiency I need to consider.

Are the 2D arrays I define limited to being either rectangles or squares? I only need to store the position of particles in each container. What I am afraid of is that my matrix will look like this:

| | | | |

| | | | |

| | | | |

| | | | |

for the 4x4 case. With the entry of the column being the position of the particles in each bin/container and number of particles differing from bin to bin I wonder if something like this is possible:

| | | | |           4 particles in first bin

| | |               2 particles in second bin, the memory occupied being 2x less than the one above

| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |  this many in third bin and so on.

I will also be needing to remove elements in rows (reducing row size) or adding elements in rows (increasing row size) or in columns depending on which way I implement my algo and would appreciate it if you could warn me beforehand if there are common mistakes when dealing with vectors of multiple dimensions as I am sure to make one, being new to the programming language :)

Comment: Vectors only have one dimension. You can have a vector of vectors if you like ("jagged"), or use Boost.MultiArray for multi-dimensional ("rectangular") arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a vector of vectors: `vector<vector<Particle> >`

Comment: A jagged array (a vector of vectors is a jagged array) would still waste space to the "left" of occupied grid cells.  There would still be cells with empty contents.

Answer (score 0):

At first, when you ask about "2D arrays ... limited to ... rectangles or squares" it sounds like you are asking how to represent "jagged" arrays (arrays that are not rectangular, but have a fixed "height", with a variable "width" per-row).

But `"tetris" shapes` ([tetraminos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino)) don't lend themselves particularly to jagged arrays.  It makes me think you actually want [a *sparse* array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix).  That is, you'd like to store only positions of particles, and not store positions of non-particles.

The easiest way to do this is to simply skip the grid, and directly maintain a list of positions of occupied spaces/particles.

```
struct Position
{
    float X;
    float Y;
};

// ...

std::vector<Position> particles; // std::list works too...
```

But plain lists aren't very efficient for some purposes.  If you need to have spatially indexed access to these, for example to find out how many particles are in a given volume/area within your simulation, then you should use [a space partitioning data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning) that still allows sparse population.

People commonly do this the way you are describing, with a rectangular grid, then storing a list *inside* each grid location of the particles contained in that grid cell.  But that "wastes space" for grid cells that aren't used.  It doesn't solve the sparse population problem.

A popular data structure that supports both spatial indexing and sparse population is [a quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).